# assetic giving 404 for css

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I am using assetic in *normal php*. I am getting 404 on css file what mistake am i doing

**controller**

```
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('backend/templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        //'cache' => 'backend/static/gen/templates',
    ));

    use Assetic\Factory\AssetFactory;
    use Assetic\Extension\Twig\AsseticExtension;
    use Assetic\FilterManager;
    use Assetic\Filter\LessFilter;

    $fm = new FilterManager();
    $fm->set('less', new LessFilter());

    $factory = new AssetFactory(dirname(__FILE__).'/backend/static/');
    $factory->setFilterManager($fm);
    $factory->setDebug(true);

    $twig->addExtension(new AsseticExtension($factory));


    echo $twig->render($current_template,$data);
```

**view**

```
{% stylesheets '{{ STATIC_PATH }}less/bootstrap.less' filter='less' output='gen/all.css' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: What is `{{ STATIC_PATH }}`? According to [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets), you have no reason to use something like `{{ STATIC_PATH }}`.